# Keep latest100 records group by device id

Tags: sql

We have one table in which we have columns like device id, Id, and other details.

We want to keep latest 100 records per device ID and delete others.

Is there any way we can write SQL query without While Loop?

EDIT -

I used following queries -

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempTable 

CREATE TABLE #TempTable(
SiteID varchar(70),
DeviceID varchar(70),
Total int)


Insert into #TempTable
select  siteId, deviceId, count(*) as cc from  [dbo].[logs]
group by siteId, deviceId  
HAVING COUNT(*) = 100

Declare @siteId varchar(70),
@deviceId varchar(70),
@Total int


While (Select Count(*) From #TempTable) > 0
Begin

    Select Top 1 @siteId = SiteID, @deviceId = DeviceID, @Total = Total From #TempTable;
    
    WITH T
     AS (select top (@Total-100) * from Logs where siteID = @siteID and deviceID = @deviceID order by esn asc)
    
    DELETE FROM T 
    

    Delete #TempTable Where SiteID = @siteId and   DeviceID = @deviceId 

End
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data is also helpful.

Comment: For anything more detailed than just 'yes', please supply sample data and specifics of how "latest" is determined.

Comment: Does the code depicted actually work as expected?

Comment: Yes, But i want to optimized

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the rows using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by device_id order by <ordering column> desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 100;
```

`<ordering column>` is however you define "latest" in the table.  It might be the `id` if that is auto-incrementing.  It might be a creation datetime or something else.

If you want to delete the older rows, then one method is:

```
delete from t
    where t.<ordering column> not in (select t2.<ordering column>
                                      from t t2
                                      where t2.device_id = t.device_id
                                      order by t2.<ordering column> desc
                                      fetch first 100 rows only
                                     );
```

Note:  This might not be the most efficient method; that depends on the database.  It also assumes that `<ordering column>` is never `NULL`.

Also, if there is a lot of data, it is often better to use the first query to just create a new table.